# "Better Code" + User Input

Tags: java, input

So I just created a little program, which prints out a Box of Stars after asking the User to input a specific height and width of the Box, for example:
height: 4; width: 5 would print out this
Starbox :

[image]

Here is my code

```
import java.util.*;
public class Stars {
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int height = scan.nextInt();
    public static Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int width = scan.nextInt();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        drawBox(height, width);
    }
    public static void drawBox(int height, int width) {
        drawStars(width);
        drawStarsWithSpaces(height, width);
        drawStars(width);
    }
    public static void drawStars(int width) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void drawStarsWithSpaces(int height, int width) {
        for (int x = 0; x < height - 2; x++) {
            System.out.print("*");
            for (int i = 0; i < width - 2; i++) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            System.out.print("*");
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

My first Question now is, how do implement a Text saying "Height of the Box" and after that "Width of the Box" when I start the program, so the user knows what to input.

Next thing is that I heard, to not use global variables for some reason and that I should implement code only after the main method... but what would the code of the program with these requirements look like?

Comment: `String.out.print("input height: ")` right before invoking `Scanner` and remove `static` from all methods and variables and invoke non static by  `new Stars().drawBox(h,w)`

Comment: I removed your first paragraph as it's just noice, we don't care about if your code is good or not, if there are improvements to it while answering your question, we'll point it out, that's why we're here. The same goes with your English, as long as we can understand it (and I can and I'm not an English native speaker) you're good to go. However you might want to take the [tour] :)

Comment: Are you sure this isn't better for https://codereview.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I agree with @Stewart however you should first read this [Guide to CodeReview for StackOverflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) before posting there... and follow their guidelines as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need two `Scanner`s. One is enough.

Second, the comments on your code are right - it's considered bad practice to use `static` variables if they're not needed (That's what you referenced as 'global').

These values should be internal to the `main` function (Which should read the values and invoke appropriate functions, so they should be declared and used in it, and not outside of it.
It would look like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int width = input.nextInt(), height.nextInt();
    ...
}
```

As for running code only after `main`: you initialize `width` and `height` in deceleration. As they're declared `static`, they're initialized the moment the class is loaded.
Before `main` has an opportunity to be run!
That is also considered bad practice.
And one more thing - it means you can't run any code before the `nextInt()` happens (Well, you *could* initialize another `static` variable with a method that would print the desired instructions...).

To summarize:
Make all the variables you use local to `main` and then you could print (using `System.out.println()`) whatever you wanted before scanning the next input (as scanning will happen in `main` itself.